# Jenkins Multi-Branch Project

Tags: jenkins

I have mistakenly deleted the Multi-Branching Project on Jenkins, (luckily everything is on GitHub)

So I recreated the Same Project!

I have the jenkins as a code pipeline in all projects,
I have a step where I'm merging develop/staging branches into master. 
And Jenkins is failing to merge it. with error `"https://github.com" no such address"`.

Have I configured something wrong in the workspace?

Comment: What's the full error message?

Answer (score 1):

Try switiching from https to SSH

```
git@github.com:user_name/repository.git
```

instead of

```
https://github.com/user_name/repository.git
```

When using Https, you will have to added username/password which might be incorrect in your case, if the password happens to be a secret key try getting the original key, if that's not possible, then create a new one and use it.